# Find parameter "$a$" given an implicit curve and a tangent

Tags: derivatives

Thus question is related to a specific problem. I don't know how kindly you take to that.

Anyways, given this curve

$ y^2 x + a = x^2 + y^2 $

And this tangent

$ y = \frac{3}{2} x - 2 $

find $a$.

I've tried lot's of things. First I calculated the derivative of the curve, then I figured it must be equal to $3/2$. Then, in the resulting equation, I expressed $x$ using $y$ and tried to insert that $x$ both into the curve, and the tangent. Neither of those attempts lead to anything. I always get some ugly numbers that don't appear correct when I input them into wolfram alpha.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the point of tangency be $(p,q)$.

By implicit differentiation, we have $y^2+2xyy' =2x+2yy'$.

Since the slope at $(p,q)$ is $3/2$, we get 
$$q^2+3pq=2p+3q.\tag{$1$}$$
Also, since $(p,q)$ is on the tangent line, we have
$$q=\frac{3}{2}p-2.\tag{$2$}$$ 
Use $(2)$ to substitute for $p$ in $(1)$. We get the  quadratic equation $9q^2-q-8=0$.  The quadratic even factors nicely. Thank you, problem setter!

Finally, substitute for $p$ and $q$ in the equation of the curve to find $a$.

Comment: Hey! That was way simpler than I thought it would be. Thanks a ton. Btw., does it make a difference if we use (2) to substitute for q in (1)?

Comment: You are welcome. Always good to hear that the problem is now viewed as simple. As to the variable one substitutes for, it makes no difference, but I think you will find my choice takes a few seconds less.